# Flutter (Dart): Get/Record audio stream from microphone and play it back immediately (real-time)

Tags: audio, dart, flutter, real-time, microphone

I need to be able to capture a stream of audio from the microphone and then pass it as argument or read it immediately in order to play it back as audio. To implement this in any other framework there are excellent tools and functions you can use but I need to archive that functionality on Flutter.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Check out the [audio_recorder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audio_recorder) and [audioplayer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayers) packages.

Comment: hi @KirollosMorkos, I was playing around with this one medcorder_audio, but thanks for your recommendations! I will try and update the post here with any outcome

Comment: @oetoni did you find anything.
I am working on video call fetcher  so I want to switch audio to speaker phone

Comment: Hi @Jigar, yet no because I was off, but I plan this weekend to finish that task. I will reply here for sure

Comment: thanks Let me know @oetoni

Comment: Any package for flutter web?

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Check this example of the flutter_sound library: https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/blob/master/flutter_sound/example/README.md#streamloop

Comment: Any crossplatform solution? Android/iOS/Web/MacOS/Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Please try this package flutter_sound. 
https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound 
Here is reference link 
https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-sound-plugin-audio-recorder-player-e5a455a8beaf

Creating instance.

```
FlutterSound flutterSound = new FlutterSound();
```

Starting recorder with listener.

```
String path = await flutterSound.startRecorder(null);
print('startRecorder: $path');

_recorderSubscription = flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
  DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
  String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
});
```

Stop recorder

```
String result = await flutterSound.stopRecorder();
print('stopRecorder: $result');

if (_recorderSubscription != null) {
    _recorderSubscription.cancel();
    _recorderSubscription = null;
}
```

Start player

```
String path = await flutterSound.startPlayer(null);
print('startPlayer: $path');

_playerSubscription = flutterSound.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((e) {
    if (e != null) {
        DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
        String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
        this.setState(() {
            this._isPlaying = true;
            this._playerTxt = txt.substring(0, 8);
        });
    }
});
```